# How can I get the file pointer position of an opened file that is being read by some process?

Tags: ruby, linux, file, pointers, progress-bar

I have a Ruby script which upload files to a popular file sharing site, but I would like to implement a progress bar. So I am curious about how can I monitor the already transferred data amount when the file upload is in progress, or equivalently the file pointer position of an opened file. Maybe there is any command that can report this and it could be called in every five seconds. I think of "lsof" that may be capable to show the file pointer, but I am not sure.

Comment: did you consider using CURL commandline as it show progress for file uploading and you can parse the output with ruby?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `man lsof`?

`lsof -o` seems to output the file pointer.
So, you have get the PID of the process.
But using lsof, of course, is nothing you want to do in a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ruby-progressbar](https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar), which might have everything you need. You could count the files that you're uploading with:

```
Dir.entries("my_directory_here").size - 2 # subtract 2 to get rid of '.' and '..'
```

then initialize your `progressbar` object with that info.